# multiple submits in form post

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Stumped; I have created a form with data submitted through ajax everything seems to work perfectly except.... After I submited the next submit adds two forms of the data and then three and then four. Your help would be appreciated as always thanks.... learning from you

```
<form name="form_page_2" id="form_page_2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div> 
    <label class="form_0">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="route_name" name="route_name" class="input" value="">
    <label class="red" id="lable_route_name"></label>
</div>
<a href="javascript:insertForm()">insert</a>
```

then insert form is :

```
function insertForm     (form){

form.submit(function(e){
    var $this=$(this);
    var postData;
    postData = $this.serializeArray();
    var inputResult=checkFormInputs(form);
    if(checkAllInputs(inputResult)==false){
        return false;
        };
        $.ajax({
            url : 'post_server.php',
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(dataPost, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(dataPost);
                },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //if fails      
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        });
form.submit(); 
}
```

the checkAllInputs returns true/false if all inputs are correctly checked even when this returns  false the next submit will add "two" submits??

Console returning print_r

Array
(
[route_name] => this is a test
)
Array
(
[route_name] => this is a test
)

two submits?

Comment: why do you have the form.submit() function? With this you are always calling the form again and again... sort of a recursive loop.

Comment: I think it doesn't need to make 'form.submit()' in insertForm() function

Comment: the bottom one? i got this code from another post in this site